Pymem pymem.exception.CouldNotOpenProcess: Could not open process
After running my code I am getting an error:

pymem.exception.CouldNotOpenProcess: Could not open process: 16908

code which I am using:
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *


mem = Pymem("app.exe")
game_module = module_from_name(mem.process_handle, "app.exe").lpBaseOfDll


def getPtrAddr(address, offsets):
    addr = mem.read_int(address)
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            addr = mem.read_int(addr + offset)
    addr = addr + offsets[-1]
    return addr


while True:

   # mem.write_int(getPtrAddr(game_module + 0x00029B80, [0x4, 0x44, 0x48, 0x38, 0x2A0]), 1000)
    mem.read_int(getPtrAddr(game_module + 0x00029B80, [0x4, 0x44, 0x48, 0x38, 0x2A0]),)


I am running that as administrator, which I could observe recently as solution, therefore it is not the case.
Do you have any clue, guesses what it could be?
I've tried to run it as admin as that was a recent solution.
